# Trying to install CocoaPods using terminal getting command not found

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash

Im trying to install CocoaPods using terminal. In their official website it is written:

```
installing it is as easy as running the following commands in the terminal:
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
$ pod setup
```

But when i enter the first line in terminal i get the following error:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

What can I do with it, I tried looking in the web but since I'm a noob with terminal I couldn't really figure out what to to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the $ in the lines shown is meant to represent the command prompt of the terminal.

enter the commands without the $ preceding..also the [sudo] part represents the requirement to use sudo or not (you will probably need to) so this comes down to entering

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

before embarking further on your exploration of the command prompt you might find it helpful to have a look through some of the resources on this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/13979/whats-the-best-way-to-learn-mac-os-x-command-line)